# Element type invalid in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-button

I'm new to react native and I'm following along with a tutorial. This is my App.js file:
**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect,FlatList } from 'react';
import {View,Text,ImageBackground,Button} from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';

const ArticleItem = ({article}) => {
  const { description, url, urlToImage } = article;
  return (
    <View>
      <Image source={{ uri: urlToImage }} />
      <Text>
        { title }
      </Text>
      <Text>
        { description }
      </Text>
      <Button onPress = { () => { console.log("Button pressed!")} } title="Open" />
      <Button onPress = { () => { console.log("Button pressed!") } } title="Read later" />
    </View>
  )
}

const SplashScreen = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style = { styles.container } >
    <ImageBackground  style= { styles.backgroundImage } source={{uri: 'http://i.imgur.com/IGlBYaC.jpg'}} >
            
      <View style= { styles.logoContainer }>
        <Text style = { styles.logoText }>
          Newzzz
        </Text>
        <Text style = { styles.logoDescription }>
          Get your doze of daily news!
        </Text>
        
      </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
} 

const HomeScreen = (props) => {
  console.log("articles: ", props.articles);
  return (
    <View>
        <FlatList
          data={ props.articles }
         // renderItem={({item}) => <ArticleItem article = { item }  />}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          renderItem={({item}) => <ArticleItem article = { item }/>}
        />
    </View>
  );
} 

const App = () => {
  const URL = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nimramubashir/React-Native/fetch/articles.json';
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(URL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson.articles;
    })
    .then( articles  => {
      setArticles(articles);
      console.log(articles);
      setLoading(false);
    })
    .catch( error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
    
  } , []);
  
  if (loading){
      return <SplashScreen />
    } else {
      return <HomeScreen articles = { articles }/>
  }
};

export default App
```

I'm getting the following although I don't think I have any problems with the import/export statements.

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `HomeScreen`.

This error occurred after I changed my `ArticleItem` component and added buttons. I'm importing the Button component. Is there any problem with the `HomeScreen` component? I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

You have not imported `FlatList` which you render in `HomeScreen`.

Comment: Or you forgot to import `title` in your  `ArticleItem` component

Comment: I'm importing FlatlLst in the code and the issue still persists

Comment: Yes, and i also forgot to import Image that's why it wasn't working. @Auticcat